# Proving $\lim_{x \to 2}x^2 = 4$ true

Tags: limits, inequality, absolute-value

I have this limit: $\lim_{x \to 2}x^2 = 4$ and I want to prove it, so I solve $|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$

$|x^2-2|<\epsilon$

$2-\epsilon<x^2<2+\epsilon$

and here I don't know what to do, can you help me?

Comment: At the very least you want to be looking at $|x^2 - 4\$ with $|x- 2|<\delta$.

Comment: While it's $x\to7$ instead, have a look at my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2373285/limits-by-definition-a-conceptual-doubt/2373315 It should tell you everything you need to know. I'm sure this exact question, perhaps with other numbers in place of $2$ or $7$, has been asked a lot of other times as well.

Comment: @S.vanNigtevecht Yes I'm sorry! I meant to say that

Comment: you need to show that $|x^2-4|<\varepsilon$, and here's a hint : $x^2-4=(x-2)(x+2)$.

Comment: @yanko I think I need the full proof :(

Comment: The proof is in your earlier question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2391382/how-to-prove-lim-x-to-2-x2-4-and-make-sure-its-correct, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

Given $\epsilon>0$,  you look for $\delta $ such that

$$|x-2|<\delta \implies |\color {green}{x+2} ||x-2|<\epsilon $$

As $x $ goes to $2$, it means that $x $ is not far from $2$, so we can assume that $$|x-2|<\color {red}{1} $$

$$\implies -1 <x-2 <1 $$
$$\implies 3 <\color {green}{x+2} <5$$

$$\implies$$
$$ |x^2-4|=|\color {green}{x+2}||x-2|<5|x-2|.$$

thus

$\Bigl (5|x-2|<\epsilon $ and $|x-2|<\color {red}{1} $

$\implies |x^2-4|<\epsilon\Bigr) $.

To satisfy this last condition, we need
$|x-2|<\frac {\epsilon}{5} $ and $|x-2|<\color {red}{1} $

hence we will take $\delta=\min (\frac {\epsilon}{5},\color {red}{1}) $.

Comment: if this is hint,what is the prove? :)

Comment: It's a very substantial hint. I would say it's so substantial it doesn't deserve the name "hint".

Comment: you have a typo: a limit is defined by $0<|x-2|<\delta$, you mixed with the definition of continuity that is $|x-2|<\delta$

Comment: @Masacroso No typo. here $f (2) $ is defined $(=4) $ so no problem.

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima Yes typo (or an actual mistake, if that is to your liking). Here the assignment is to check the limit as $x\to2$, not continuity at $x=2$. That means $0<|x-2|$ regardless of whether it works without it.

Comment: @Arthur $f (2) =4$  so if $|x-2|=0$ then $|f (2)-4|=0<\epsilon $. BUT YOU ARE RIGHT.

Comment: It is true that continuity at $a$ requires more than that the limit exists. But this means that establishing continuity also shows the limit exists and is $f(a).$